# Migrating a huge amount of data using Flyway

Tags: oracle, sybase, flyway

How to migrate a table with over 100,000 records using Flyway?
I am doing data migration from Sybase to Oracle.

What I understood from the software is that we have to create script files (`.sql`) and then migrate. I want to know:

1. If we can directly point to the source and destination and migrate the database?
2. As I am new, I am having problem in connecting to the databases. Can someone give some configuration file examples for connecting to Sybase, Oracle and SQL server databases with clearly specifying user name, password, server name or IP address and all the things we need to specify to get connected?

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: I have to migrate data from sybase to oracle database, but what i understood from the software is that we have to create scripts files(.sql)and then migrate. i want to know-1)if we can directly point to the source and destination and migrate the database? 2) as i am new i am having problem in connecting to the databases so can someone give some configuration files examples for connecting to sybase, oracle and sql server databases with clearly specifying- user name, password, server name or ip address and all the things we need to specify to get connected. thank you in advance

Comment: I have moved your comment into the question itself. It's still not a great question as it is very broad; try making it more specific by showing what you've already tried and where specifically you failed.